# How to change UI of application to match OS behavior in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, themes

I want to change my UI according to OS version my app is running on.

Eg.: If I run my application on 2.2 it should take its default UI themes for views and if I run the app on ics 4.0, it should take its default theme for views.

That is, I want my app to match OS behavior.

Comment: It will do this by default if you are not supplying your own view resources...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to achieve this.

1) The easiest way - add this line to your android-manifest file under  tag

```
< android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

2) if you are applying your own style.xml for your UI component then make a folder **values-vX**

where **X** is OS api level number that u want to run ur app on. and add style.xml file and make changes in it accordingly.e.g Holo theme is used from api 11 so u can add it to ur style.xml in **values-v11** Follow this **developer** [**link**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/values-v11/styles.html)

so ur res dir may have **values ,values-v8 ,values-v11** and so on with their own style.xml

and style.xml(default) in values will adjust itself depending on the API version.
see this **developer api demo** [**link**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/values/styles.html)